# adding options to the ckeditor inline tool bar not working

Tags: ckeditor

I'm having some trouble adding toolbar options to the CKEditor4 inline toolbar option.  I've been reading the docs and still can't figure out where my problem is.

I'm creating a div on the fly, then adding the CKEditor to the div.  Everything works fine, but I want to remove some of the tool bar options and add some other ones.  When I add parameters to the inline() call nothing changes?

Here is how I create the instance on the fly:

```
.on('dblclick', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    ed.ck_restore();
    ed.ck_active_block = $(this).attr("id");
    ed.ck_block_data = $(this).html();
    var block_width = $(this).css("width"); 
    var block_height = $(this).css("height")+20;
    var block_padding_top = $(this).css("padding-top");
    var block_padding_right = $(this).css("padding-right");
    var block_padding_bottom = $(this).css("padding-bottom");
    var block_padding_left = $(this).css("padding-left");
    var padding = 'padding-top: '+block_padding_top+';padding-right: '+block_padding_right+';padding-bottom: '+block_padding_bottom+';padding-left: '+block_padding_left+';';

    var editor = '<div id="edit" contenteditable="true" style="margin-top: -'+block_padding_top+'; margin-left: -'+block_padding_left+';'+padding+' width: '+block_width+'; height: '+block_height+';background-color: #fff;position: absolute;">'+ed.ck_block_data+'</div>';

    $("#"+ed.ck_active_block).prepend(editor);

    if(CKEDITOR.instances.edit)
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances.edit.destroy(); //remove any previously created instances 
    }

    CKEDITOR.inline("edit",
                    [CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_style = {
                        element: 'span',
                        styles: { 'font-size': '#(size)' },
                        overrides: [ {
                            element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': null }
                        }]
                    }]
                    );

    $("#edit").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();}).focus();
    $("w_save").text("1");
});
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline

The docs imply I can pass a configuration parameter to change the options, but I'm missing something and after 3 hours of trying I need a bit of help.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that meant to be:

```
 CKEDITOR.inline("edit",
                [CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_style = {
                    element: 'span',
                    styles: { 'font-size': '#(size)' },
                    overrides: [ {
                        element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': null }
                    }]
                }]
                );
```

It is invalid JavaScript code. Have you checked your JS console?

Anyway, `CKEDITOR.inline` accepts two arguments - name and config **object**.

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'edit', {
    fontSize_style: {
        element: 'span',
        styles: { 'font-size': '#(size)' },
        overrides: [
            { element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': null } }
        ]
    },
    language: 'pl',
    removeButtons: 'Bold,Italic' // or set toolbar or toolbarGroups.
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Reinmar.  I was able to find another solution.  Here is the code for others:

CKEDITOR.inline("edit",{customConfig : "mycustomConfig.js"});

This referenced a custom config file, I just pulled it from an example config on the CKEditor site and changed some of the options.  Works now.